# What is start-stop-daemon in linux scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, init.d, start-stop-daemon

What is start-stop-daemon and how should it be used?

I am trying to automate a particular program to run. Whenever the system starts, the program should run. For that I am writing script in `/etc/init.d/` location.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It is a program to manage the start and stop of system level background processes (daemons). You use it by passing in parameters (such as the pid file to create/check) and command arguments for the process you want to launch.

Then, you do one of two things:

`start-stop-daemon -S [other arguments] something`

start `something`, if `something` wasn't already running. If it was running, do nothing.

`start-stop-daemon -K [other arguments] something`

stop `something`. If `something` wasn't running, do nothing.

The [man page](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon) provides more information on the various arguments. Typically a template is provided in `/etc/init.d/` which has other commands for the init process that controls the running of background processes.

---

#### What does it mean?

> start-stop-daemon --start --background -m --oknodo
>   --pidfile ${PIDFILE} --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${TARGETDIR}

- `--background` = launch as a background process
- `-m` = make a PID file. This is used when your process doesn't create its own PID file, and is used with `--background`
- `--oknodo` = return `0`, not `1` if no actions are taken by the daemon
- `--pidfile ${PIDFILE}` = check whether the PID file has been created or not
- `--exec` = make sure the processes are instances of this executable (in your case, `DAEMON`)

Comment: Is it universal though ? on debian, it seems to be coming from the dpkg package. I wonder if this is provided by other distros under the same name too, or if they use other tools.

Comment: @ychaouche No it's not. RedHat-based distros don't use it at all for instance. I'd only expect it to work on Debian-based systems (i.e. Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives).

Answer (score 10):

Copy the `/etc/init.d/skeleton` [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6918156/) (to e.g. `/etc/init.d/rajeevdaemon` or another good name), which is a shell script with a lot of comments, and edit it to suit your needs. Then add appropriate symlinks from e.g. `/etc/rc2.d/S98rajeevdaemon` and `/etc/rc2.d/K98rajeevdaemon` to it.

Read more about [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel).

And recent (or future) Linux distributions are using more and more [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)